# mysql sql_mode=only_full_group_by in subquery not working

Tags: mysql

I've tried a lot of ways, mentioned here and other forums, but still get stucked in it:

when I'm running the query

```
select a, group_concat(b) from table1 group by a
```

working perfectly.

Wneh I put it in a subquery, ex.

```
select table2.c, t1.conc  
from table2 
inner join (
   select a, group_concat(b) as conc 
   from table1 group by a) as t1 
on t1.a = tabke2.d`
```

I get this:

> expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains
>   nonaggregated column .... is not functionally dependent on columns in
>   GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

But why?? If it works stand alone!?

Comment: Please do not see the writing mistakes ex. tabke.

Comment: where ... is not functionally dependet is the `b`

Comment: Neither of your published queries would throw that error.

Comment: and it throws... that's why am asking... but here are more joins but this I think does not meather...

Comment: For better overview:
`select hu as kat_ki, ktdb.kdb, ka.mk, kt.fny from ck inner join (select b.hu as c, count(*) as kdb from d inner join b on b.id = d.alc group by b.c) as ktdb on ktdb.c = ck.id left join (select id, c, GROUP_CONCAT(hu) as mk from b group by c, id, hu) as ka on ka.c = ck.id inner join (select ck.id, e.hu as fny from e inner join ck on ck.faj = e.id where ck.id = 5) as kt on kt.id = ck.id where ck.id = 5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select b.hu as c, count(*) as kdb 
    from d 
    inner join b on b.id = d.alc 
    group by b.c
```

There isn't as far as I can tell b.c to group by - it looks like you are trying to group on an alias when you should be grouping by b.hu

and in this

```
select id, c, GROUP_CONCAT(hu) as mk 
    from b 
    group by c, id, hu
```

you are group_concatenating hu so it makes no sense to group by hu

In fact this query makes very little sense, if I was you I would start over and publish sample data and expected output as text in the question.